# Using weak frameworks for earlier version support in iOS with Rubymotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion, social-framework

I've built my Rubymotion app to include Facebook and Twitter posting.

the `SLComposeViewController` class required for this is only available from iOS 6.0 onwards.

I'd like to make the app available to iOS 5.0 users too.

I moved the Social and Twitter frameworks to the weak frameworks config in my rakefile:

```
app.weak_frameworks += %w{ Social Twitter }
```

And in my controller, I check if `SLComposeViewController` is defined (implying iOS > 5) before attempting to load the Facebook posting features.

```
if defined?(SLComposeViewController)
  # add the Facebook stuff
end
```

The problem I'm having is that the Facebook posting features (which should only be available from iOS 6 onwards) are being displayed and are working in the iOS 5.0 simulator.

Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: You're running your app using `rake target=5.0`, I assume?

Comment: I realised this yesterday - the simulator is always running in 6.0. My machine no longer has the iOS 5.0 SDK - how do I get it again?

Comment: I'll put it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the iOS 5.0 Simulator by opening Xcode, going to Preferences, going to Downloads, and installing from there. You can also install 5.1 and 6.0 while you're at it.

To run the iOS Simulator in 5.0 mode, do:

```
rake target=5.0
```

You can obviously also use 5.1 and 6.0 if you have those installed.

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Comment: I thought that was the case but I have the 5.0 simulator installed and still I luck... I'll investigate - thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, Xcode tells me I've installed the SDK but rubymotion complains that I havent

Comment: Do you have two versions of Xcode installed? Like the beta and stable?